# How to override heading numbering behavior in Typst

Tags: heading, typesetting, typst

I'm submitting to a journal that requires headings of the following form:

> **I. TOP LEVEL HEADING**
>
> **A. First subheading**
>
> ***1. Second subheading***

It's easy enough to do the capitalization and italicization using `#show heading.where()` and to get the numbering *almost* correct by setting the heading numbering to `"I.A.1."`.  The problem is that each heading shows all of its parents numbers, as well as its own.  So the third subsection of the first section appears as **I.C Subsection title** when I want it to just be **C Subsection title**.  Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

I tried to construct a `show heading` statement that trims off everything before the last two characters before the last space.  But the heading object you get access to isn't a string, so you can't do string operations on it.  You *can* extract the heading body, but not the number (since that's not passed to the `heading()` function; it's evaluated later). Maybbe there's a way to override `numbering()`?  Or intervene before `numbering()` gets called and only pass it the last number?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  The answer was much simpler than what I was initially attempting to do.  It turns out you can pass a function to `numbering()` instead of a string.  The `set` statement below was all I needed.

```
set heading(numbering: (..numbers) => {
  let level = numbers.pos().len()
  if (level == 1) {
    return numbering("I", numbers.pos().at(level - 1))
  } else if (level == 2) {
    return numbering("A", numbers.pos().at(level - 1))
  } else {
    return numbering("1", numbers.pos().at(level - 1))
  }
})
```